# PHP + MySQL Best practice

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm having some trouble explaining to my buddy why a specific piece of code is "bad practice", does anyone know where I can find some information on why it's a bad way to do it? (Or maybe it's just me who think it's bad).

**Here's what he wants to accomplish:**

1. Create a "dynamic form input", so he will create a table with different types of cols. And then in the file that shows the form he will just make alot of different "if type == varchar" etc. and then display a form after that
2. When saving a form he will loop thru all the $_POST data and insert it into a table depending on the key's etc.

He want's to make everything dynamic and I can see why that could be cool, but in my book this seems to be very bad practice, so is there a better way to do this or is there some articles I can show him about why this is bad etc.?

Everything is for a private admin panel, but still I feel there is a lot of issues.

Comment: what about frameworks?

Comment: sounds like developing a custom framework.

Comment: I see only 2nd one as a bad idea. Because it is very vulnerable practice. We can't control who and how and what is sending through POST, so in general this would be very insecure. But if you can implement some class to validate fields - that is possible to implement then. Try to look at this problem as a new phpMyAdmin - which is almost doing what you describe. You can manipulate with DB there, but for sure you need to limit access to such powerful tool.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect?